# MYSQL: Intermediate query results

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-parser

Is it possible to access the intermediate results generated by mysql during execution of a query??
Creating a view for the query stores the results of the query, i need to store the intermediate results of the every query for further query optimization. I couldn't find any way out for this.

There is another point i want to extract. The candidate plans for which mysql finds the costs and selects the best plan.

I used the keyword "EXPLAIN", but it gives the execution plan that mysql has used to execute the query(considering its minimum cost), but the requirement is to find all the plans that mysql has considered before selecting the best one.

I know its a very broad question but i couldn't find anything in support of the task i want to do.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @Mikpa The query execution time for future queries can be decreased  if these two factors are controlled properly.